# How to code for the BTT expansion board?

Tags: marlin

Does anyone know how to adjust the firmware for the BTT expansion module?

I am going to be using this(https://github.com/bigtreetech/BTT-Expansion-module/tree/master/BTT%20EXP-MOT) to add three additional motors and I know that I have to edit the code somehow to add the three extra drivers?

I'm not quite sure where or how but I'm guessing it has something to do with the pins.h file?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: [User guide](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BTT-Expansion-module/blob/master/BTT%20EEPROM/BTT%20EEPROM%20V1.0User%20Manual.pdf). From [BTT-Expansion-module](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BTT-Expansion-module)/[BTT EEPROM](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BTT-Expansion-module/tree/master/BTT%20EEPROM).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP btw...! :-) Sorry that your question was closed, I'm not sure exactly why it was closed. However, if you could [edit] and expand upon your question, by adding some details and explaining what you want to modify the EEPROM for, what you have tried and what didn't work, it might be possible to reopen the question. Were you having trouble understanding the user guide? The instructions in the PDF are rather terse, I must admit, and could do with some better steps and examples..